# Flutter agrgar controles dinamics

Tags: flutter, dart

se puede hacer esto sin una listview, listbuilder, etc ¿?

```
      body:
               for (i=1;i <5;i++)
               {
                   if i < 3 
                      text ('mensaje '+ i);
                   else
                      Icon(xx);              
               }
```

Me gustaría pintar la pantalla programaticamente a partir de ciertos valores ya rescatados, pero ni siquiera pude hacer un loop que pinte n veces un texto (sin listview, porque no quiero que se vea el efecto de scrolllist, solo que se vea uno o varios widget desplegados en la pantalla, programáticamente)

se agradece su ayuda. saludos

Comment: Sí, con y sin ListView se puede, por otro lado, si no tiene scroll , que pasa cuando tengas muchos elementos y no entren en la pantalla?

Comment: gracias por la información .... :)

Answer (score 0):

Solo para complementar con un ejemplo la respuesta de @diegoveloper en cualquier `Widget` que acepte una lista de widgets como argumento puedes hacer tu propio bucle por ejemplo:

`ListView`

```
body: ListView(
  children: [
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
      if (i > 3) Text('mensaje $i') else Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
  ],
),
```

`Column`

```
body: Column(
  children: [
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
      if (i > 3) Text('mensaje $i') else Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
  ],
)
```

Comment: EdHuamani --> Muy agradecido por tus ejemplos ... !!!! :):):)